# How to extract binary response for uneven matching rows between two r data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

From these two data frames `df1` and `df2`, i want to assign "yes" or "no" on `df1` based on the following conditions.
If anyone of `Date`, `Date1`, `Date2`,..., `Date6` matches with at least one Date of the `Date` column of `df1`, then it has to be `yes`, else `no`. I can easily do with `ifelse` conditions but the problem here is there are an uneven number of rows between two data frames as in this sample example and through the errors. In this case, no need to have row by row match, what I need is if any Dates from `df1`  matches with any of the Date of `df2` (at least one match) then it is yes, else no.

```
df1<-structure(list(Date = structure(3634, class = "Date"), Date1 = structure(3633, class = "Date"), 
    Date2 = structure(3632, class = "Date"), Date3 = structure(3631, class = "Date"), 
    Date4 = structure(3630, class = "Date"), Date5 = structure(3629, class = "Date"), 
    Date6 = structure(3628, class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2<-structure(list(yr = c(1979, 1979), day = c(351, 347), Date = structure(c(3637, 
3633), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df1$y_n<-if_else(df2$Date %in% df1$Date |
                 df2$Date %in% df1$Date1 |
                  df2$Date %in% df1$Date3 |
                   df2$Date %in% df1$Date4 |
                   df2$Date %in% df1$Date5 |
                   df2$Date %in% df1$Date6,"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option may be to `gather` the first data into 'long' format, after creating a row index (with `rownames_to_column` from `tibble`), then do a join with the second data (avoiding all the nested `ifelse` statements altogether), grouped by 'rn' check whether there are any non-NA elements in one of the columns not common to create the 'y_n' column and bind with the first datasset

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
   gather(key, Date, -rn) %>% 
   left_join(df2) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(y_n = c("no", "yes")[1 + any(!is.na(yr))]) %>%
   select(y_n) %>% 
   bind_cols(df1, .)
```

---

or another option is `pmap`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(y_n = pmap_lgl(.,  ~ any(c(...) %in% df2$Date)))
```

It may be better to store as logical, but if we need 'yes' or 'no'

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(y_n = pmap_chr(.,  ~ c('no', 'yes')[1 + any(c(...) %in% df2$Date)]))
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#  Date       Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4      Date5      Date6      y_n  
#  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>
#1 1979-12-14 1979-12-13 1979-12-12 1979-12-11 1979-12-10 1979-12-09 1979-12-08 yes
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, y_n := c('no', 'yes')[1 + Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, df2$Date))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can use `sapply`/`lapply` to check for dates. Assuming you'll have more than one row of data in `df1`

```
df1 <- rbind(df1,  df1)
df1$y_n <- c("no", "yes")[(rowSums(sapply(df1, `%in%`, df2$Date)) > 0) + 1]

# Date       Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4      Date5      Date6      y_n  
# <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    <chr>
#1 1979-12-14 1979-12-13 1979-12-12 1979-12-11 1979-12-10 1979-12-09 1979-12-08 yes  
#2 1979-12-14 1979-12-13 1979-12-12 1979-12-11 1979-12-10 1979-12-09 1979-12-08 yes
```

Or with `lapply`

```
df1$y_n <- c("no", "yes")[(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, `%in%`, df2$Date))) + 1]
```